# Removal of submodule commit hash value file

Tags: git, git-submodules

There is a new file being created with submodule commit hash value inside the parent repo, can I remove this file? does it work fine after removing this commit hash file?

When I tried to run ado pipeline by removing the commit hash value file pipelines are getting failed with no such file or directory. So, need consequences and importance of submodule commit hash value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.